# Webdriver.io. Highlighting multiple elements with CTRL+click on coffescript

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

It is necessary to write a test for СoffeScript using Webdrivwr.io and mocha.

The test should check the selection of several elements of the table by pressing CTRL + click. Below is an example of how I tried to do. But so only one element stands out. Please can you tell me how to do it right?

```
  it('test', () ->
    $(selector1).click()
    browser.keys('Control')
    $(selector2).click()
    browser.keys('NULL')
  )
```

Comment: Looking at the [webdriver docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/keys.html), I think it's `Ctrl` and not `Control`. The rest of your code looks correct.

Comment: Already tried to write Ctrl. Only the last item is specified anyway.

Comment: have you tried the same manually?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Everything works well

Comment: It turned out that browser.keys() did not work on Firefox. Everything works fine through Chrome.

Comment: For newer versions of wdio, I know of v6, `browser.keys` is not designed to modify clicks. In this case, you have to use `performActions` and read into the Webdriver Actions API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the browser to run the tests in Webdriver.io (this is done in the wdio.conf.js file). If Webdriver.io is running in Firefox, then you will receive uncorrect data. If you run tests in Chrome, then this problem will disappear.